# Farbtastic is broken and wont update my input fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So, I have a foreach loop creating a bunch of form fields to allow users to use farbtastic to select colors for font and such. The loop creates fields for probably 60 fields and while the colorpicking works, for whatever reason after 20 fields farbtastic stops updating the input fields with the hexcode. It changes the input field background colors but it doesn't update the field.

What's even more weird, is that all these fields are in separate tabs, and the way wordpress handles tabs is by putting each on a new page. So the page has to reload. So once you get to the later tabs (and therefore later fields) one of two of the fields will work correctly but most do not. So like, field 2 on one tab works ok, but the same field on a different tab does not.

Right now I have a single jQuery method controlling the color picker:

```
// Color Picker for js file
jQuery('.pickcolor').click( function(e) {
      colorPicker = jQuery(this).next('div');
      input = jQuery(this).prev('input');
      jQuery(colorPicker).farbtastic(input);
      colorPicker.show();
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(document).mousedown( function() {
          jQuery(colorPicker).hide();
      });
});
```

and the form fields pretty much all look like this: 
$name is the section name and $element is the thing the color is being chosen form (nested foreach loop)

```
<div class="color_option option" style="position: relative;">
    <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>_fonts"><?php echo $elementName;?> Color</label>

    <input class="link_color" type="text" id="<?php echo $name; ?>_fonts" 
name="kjd_<?php echo $name;?>_settings[kjd_<?php echo $name; ?>_fonts][<?php echo $element; ?>]" 
value="<?php echo $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element] ? $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element] : ''; ?>"

style="background:<?php echo $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element]?>; color:<?php echo $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element]?>;"   
/>

    <input type='button' class='pickcolor button-secondary' value='Select Color'>
    <div style="position: absolute;" class="colorpicker"></div>
```

So the jQuery looks right, but I wonder if I should dynamically create the jquery in the foreach loop to target each field by ID

Answer (score 0):

I solved it kinda of.

```
value="<?php echo $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element] ? $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element] : ''; ?>
```

the last part of that if-statement cant be empty, it has to be ' ' (blank space), rather, in order for farbtastic to update the input there has to be some value in there. so I used 'none' to avoid confusing users.

my code now says

```
value="<?php echo $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element] ? $options['kjd_'.$name.'_fonts'][$element] : 'none'; ?>
```